# Pseudo class ::before - create css circle

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm trying to create the circle with css, but wan't to use pseudo class ::before

This should be like that (for list of subway stations):

```
.subway-item{
 // css for text item going after circle
 }
.subway-item::before{
   width:15px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   -moz-border-radius: 15px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
   background-color:#69b6d5;
}
```

I know that it can be done with additional element before text or with image. But want to know is it possible to use such properties in ::before

Comment: It looks like your forgot to specify a `content` property.. if one isn't specified, the pseudo element isn't generated. The element is also `inline` by default, which means that you would need to set the `display` to `inline-block` if you want to set dimensions on it.. It looks like you will also need to specify a `height`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cpgrscae/1/  Created here, maybe you can try to help, this should be also with additional styles for different colors

Comment: See this updated example - http://jsfiddle.net/rL5g0wxh/

Comment: Thanks guys, now i've understood that inline block should be in ::before block! Great!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You also need to set `content`, `height` and `display` to make it actually render the pseudo element.

Example:

```css
    .subway-item::before{
       content: '';
       display: inline-block;
       width: 15px;
       height: 15px;
       -moz-border-radius: 7.5px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 7.5px;
       border-radius: 7.5px;
       background-color: #69b6d5;
    }
```

```html
<div class="subway-item"></div>
```

**Note:** It’s better to write the vendor-specific properties *before* the standard property (`border-radius` in your case).

Comment: @AlexVeryutin It should now, I’ve already changed `block` to `inline-block` a couple of minutes ago when I saw your fiddle.

Comment: It would be more logical to set the border-radius to half the width (or height).

Comment: I know this one is quite old - but there isn't a 0.5 pixel @aaronk6 :) use em instead for floating numbers.

Comment: @webprogrammer Actually there is, because these are display pixels, not device pixels. Using floating numbers is perfectly fine, and it will have a visible effect when you are on a hi-res display (or simply zoom in).

Comment: to create a circle you can also use `border-radius: 50%`